# module related to Reviews.co.uk getting time out exception

Tags: magento-1.9, review, product-review

I have a module which sync my product reviews with *Reviews.co.uk*. In the setting page of the module it is said that

> To sync your products to Reviews.co.uk you should enable your product
>   feed. The feed will be available at: /reviews/index/feed and will be
>   automatically added to your Reviews.co.uk account when you save these
>   settings.

So I want to know that the url mentioned here is belongs to where. For eg. if I trigger a URL

> [my_site_url]/reviews/index/feed/

then it throws error

> 504 Gateway Timeout

so please let me know how can I access my product feed with given URL.

PS: I have found where the exception is generated. it is in:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $prod)
{ 
....
```

I guess here they are getting all products collection and there are thousands of products. Thats why it is throwing exception. Please anyone can suggest that how can I modify this as it is third party module.

Thanks

Comment: Depends on how the module links, you have not shown the code.  If the module is keeping the connection open, then you can modify the code to open the connection, list a product (or add a counter to send a few products) then close and re-open the connection